# "Expo start" does not start Javascript bundling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

On my react native app, expo start command sometimes triggers Javascript bundling which runs the app on the device but most of the time it does not. Once I read the QR code on expo start command, the Metro bundler is stuck at "Starting Metro Bundler". I try to run the app through LAN and made sure that my phone and the computer are on the same Wifi connection, so there is no problem with that. Upon seeing other articles on this, I tried the Tunnel connection but always get the

Error starting tunnel Failed to install @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0 globally: spawn yarnpkg ENOENT

error. Ngrok somehow does not install. When I run, `expo start --tunnel` I get, `Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.`

So Tunnel does not work too. I have done anything that comes to my mind but would appreciate your help on this.

If I restart the computer and take a chance to expo start, sometimes it works. I have no clue what the reason is.